# Relationship between arcsec and arccos

Tags: trigonometry

$$\operatorname{arcsec}(x/2) = \arccos(2/x)$$

Is this correct? If so, does this apply to other inverse trigonometric ratios and their reciprocal inverses as well?

Comment: Seems to be correct indeed.

Comment: You might want to check arctangent and arccotangent.

Comment: If they are $(u,v)$ then $u=v, 2 \pi- v$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed. It can be proven in the following way. If $y=\arccos(2/x)$, then $\cos(y)=2/x$ (with $0 \leq y \leq \pi$). Taking reciprocals, we find that
$$
\sec(y)=\frac{x}{2} \, ,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
y=\operatorname{arcsec}(x/2) \, .
$$
Note that $\sec$, like other trigonometric functions, doesn't actually have an inverse. There are many values of $y$ such that $\sec(y)=x/2$. However, because we know that $0 \leq y \leq \pi$ (and the range of $\text{arcsec}$ is precisely that), we can draw the above conclusion. This should be somewhat intuitive, since $\sec$ is simply the reciprocal function of $\cos$.